# about ElasticSearch jdbc river

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

**In my MySQL:**

```
mysql> select * from cc;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | aa   |
|  2 | bb   |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**and elasticsearch jdbc river is:**

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9201/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3301/test",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "root",
    "poll" : "10s",
    "strategy" : "simple",
        "sql" : "select * from cc"
    }
}'
```

**but,I don't understand elasticsearch index data why result is:**

```
aa
bb
aa
bb
aa
aa
aa
bb
bb
bb
```

**I think result like this:**

```
aa
bb
```

please help me, and thanks gsc-leticia help me format this question content.

Comment: Question? What question? What are you talking about? Please format your post.

Comment: Clarify which is your intention with the code and your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You did not define an _id so the river add your documents every minutes.

You should define your river with something like:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9201/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3301/test",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "root",
    "poll" : "10s",
    "strategy" : "simple",
        "sql" : "select id as _id, name from cc"
    }
}'
```

See [JDBC River documentation](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Labeled-columns) for details.

Comment: Hi,dude,Thanks,I will be try it.